# Windows Phone apps coding (more pages)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone

I am trying to make an app for the windows phone , but I don't know how to make new "pages".

Currently I'm using `.visibility` but if I am working on a bigger project, I can't use this anymore:

```
Button.Visibility =System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed; 
Button2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 1):

Right-click your project name in the Solution Explorer, select Add from the menu, and then New Item. Then choose the type of page you want to add.

Moving from page to page is easy there is a tutorial [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that will help I hope.